# Shortest CSS selector to select ALL html elements, without using asterisk *

Tags: code-golf, tips, restricted-source, css

What is the shortest selector (by character count) to select ALL html elements on a web page, without using asterisk (*)? Some examples are the following:

```
a,:not(a) /*9 chars*/

:nth-child(n) /*12 chars*/

:link,:not(:link) /*17 chars*/
```

Comment: In Firefox at least, there's no HTML `·` element (it's an illegal tag name), so could you shorten `a,:not(a)` to `:not(·)`?

Comment: @Neil That's interesting. What is the significance of the middle dot character (U+00B7)? Was it just a random character you chose?

Comment: It was the first one I found where `document.createElement` threw an error but `:not` did not.

Comment: @Neil After playing around with some more special symbols, I was curious to know if there were any "standard" symbols could be typed from a keyboard. The only symbol I could get to work that exists on a keyboard is a double backslash: `:not(\\)`. I wonder why and how that works, but something like `:not(^)` does not.

Comment: @Neil Update: other characters also work when preceded by a backslash, for example `:not(\*)` and `:not(\#)`